# Php/Ajax Multiple Images Upload - One by one

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

My webhost only allows maximum 20 images upload per request.
Is it possible to run an ajax/php request X times?

Example: I am trying to upload 61 images. Then run the upload 61 times and bypass the maximum 20 upload limit?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `xampp control panel > Config > PHP (php.ini)`

and change these: depending on what you want.

```
post_max_size=27000M
max_file_uploads = 200
upload_max_filesize=27000M
max_execution_time=28800
memory_limit=27000M
```